# Angularjs website with two layout pages

Tags: angularjs

I want my website to have two master pages

1. site layout with a header and a footer
2. adminlayout with a navbar how do I build using ui-router module.

And how to place content pages in this architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ui-router` allows to define nested views.

If you want to support multiple layout. Define the root view without any layout and move it to level 1 (`site-layout-root` or `admin-layout-root`)

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you say how my index.html look like should I define two named ui-views on index.html?

Comment: You can define nested views. The index.html doesn't have a layout. You define the layouts with sub-views on the first view level and place. Just like a tree. If the index.html contains only a `ui-view` you can put in there whatever pages and layout you want.

Comment: Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ITxDeNsG2Irre13480Hj?p=preview) - hope it helps

Comment: I created the layouts and one test contentpage, It works but only when I click a link with sref="site.movies", I want this movies.html load when site first loads. my app.js is:

Comment: app.js:  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Site/Movies");


        $stateProvider
          .state('admin', {
              url: "/Admin",
              templateUrl: "/Views/Admin.html"
          })
          .state('site', {
              url: "/Site",
              templateUrl: "/Views/Site.html"
          })          
          .state('site.movies', {
              url: "/Site/Movies",
              templateUrl: "/Views/Site/movies.html",
              controller: 'moviesController'
          })